# Are there creatures that are immune to critical hits?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, critical-hit

My thinking behind this is to do with the property of Adamantine Armour which states that "While you're wearing it, any critical hit against you becomes a normal hit" (DMG, p.150).

I wondered if there are any creatures that have this feature "naturally"? - possibly as a result of their skin/scales being so hard or because of another innate feature (but not spell-casting).

I am looking for answers with reference examples of creatures from the 5th edition in the officially published materials.

I'm not looking for a list per se but, if the prevalence of this feature in 5e is not exhaustive, then a list would be fine, too.

Comment: Does my answer solve your problem well enough for a green check?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### The Lord of Blades

From *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*, the [Lord of Blades](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/the-lord-of-blades) has the Adamantine Plating feature:

> ***Adamantine Plating.*** Any critical hit against the Lord of Blades becomes a normal hit.

Notably, no creatures in the three monster books (MM, VGtM, MToF) have a similar feature.

#### Honorable Mention: Caduceus Clay, Grave Cleric

If you have watched *Critical Role* campaign 2, you will be familiar with the Grave Cleric’s 6th level feature Sentinel at Death’s Door:

> At 6th level, you gain the ability to impede death’s progress. As a reaction when you or a creature you can see within 30 feet of you suffers a critical hit, you can turn that hit into a normal hit. Any effects triggered by a critical hit are canceled. (XGtE, p. 20)

It is not at all uncommon to see this exchange:

> Matt (Dungeon Master): Natural 20 on the attack roll!
>
> Taliesin (Caduceus Clay): CANCEL!

Comment: Might be worth adding that (from a search via PDF) I have found no such creatures in the MM, VGtM or MToF, which are the main 'monster' books.

Comment: As a related topic, do any creatures have the ability to cast Sentinal at Death's Door?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson No. A DM could make an NPC with class levels that could use the feature.